# Logic Error - Need this to calculate starting at 1, not starting at 2

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this to read the first 'counter' instead of calculating hours 1 as 0.0. It should calculate the speed instead, at the first hour.

If I can't explain what I mean well enough, run the code. You will notice that at 1 (since it prints a long list) the second number is 0.0. Say I enter in 20 for the MPH and 15 for the hours. When it prints this 20.0 doesn't come up until number 2. I need it to pop-up at number 1. I know this has to be the most basic question there is, but I just cannot figure it out :/

OUTPUT:

```
1   0.0

2   20.0

3   40.0

4   60.0

5   80.0

6   100.0

7   120.0

8   140.0

9   160.0

10   180.0

11   200.0

12   220.0

13   240.0

14   260.0

15   280.0

Distance traveled by Smith was 300 miles.
```

MY CODE:

```
 def main ():

    greet()

    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    print()

    speed = float(input("Please enter, in miles per hour, your speed (Between 20-500 MPH): "))

    while speed < 20 or speed > 500:
        print("You must enter a speed between 20-500 MPH")
        print()
        speed = float(input("Please try again: "))
        print()

    print("That speed is accepted.")
    print()

    time = int(input("Please enter, in hours, your travel time (Between 2-15 hours): "))    

    while time < 2 or time > 15:
        print("You must enter a time between 2-15 hours.")
        print()
        time = int(input("Please try again: "))
        print()

    print("That time is accepted.")
    print()

    totaldistance = speed * time
    totaldistance = int(totaldistance)

    for count in range (time):
        distance = speed * count
        print_data(name, distance, count, time)

    print()
    print("Distance traveled by", name,"was", totaldistance,"miles.") 

def greet ():
    print()
    print("This program calculates distance traveled.")
    print()

def print_data (name, distance, count, time):
    print()
    print(format(count + 1), " ", format(distance))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your offset arises from adding 1 to `count` inside `print_data`, but not when calculating the distance.

Try this:

```
for count in range (1, time):
    distance = speed * count
    print_data(distance, count)
```

together with

```
def print_data (distance, count):
    print()
    print(count, distance)
```

Comment: When I did this the reaction to the 1 inclusive to the 'for range' eliminated my first line (1    0.0) but did not solve the issue. 2 was still (2     20.0). To better explain this, I think something is multiplying itself by zero, but I cannot see where I did that

Comment: @user3399963 Then you have only changed the loop, but not the function `print_data`. There is nothing multiplying itself stealthily. This is really programming 101...

Answer (score 0):

```
for count in range (time):
    distance = speed * count
    print_data(name, distance, count, time)
```

If this is the printout, then you are starting with the first value of count as 0, since that starts the range. Since count = 0, then speed*0 = 0 and your print_data will always have

```
print(format(1), " ", format(0))
```

as the first output